# something like partial/selective np.ndenumerate?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570050/numpy-ndarray-enumeration-over-a-proper-subset-of-the-dimensions) and suspect I need to understand indexing better. I would like to do something like `np.ndenumerate`, but (in this particular case) only over the first three dimensions, returning a series of vectors:

```
x = np.linspace(0., 1., 4)
y = np.linspace(0., 1., 5)
z = np.linspace(0., 1., 2)
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)   # define a grid
F = np.zeros(X.shape + (3,))     # a 3D vector field 
F = np.random.rand(5*4*2*3).reshape(5,4,2,3)   # added this later just to give non-zero for testing

thetas = np.linspace(0, 2.*np.pi, 21)[:-1]    # drop the duplicate
v = np.array([(np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta), 0.0) for theta in thetas])

for tup, vec in magical_enumerate(F, axis=(0,1,2)):  # it's magic! (need correct expression)
    F(tup) = np.cross(v, vec).sum(axis=0)     # sum over 20 vectors in v
```

Is there a way to do this without lots of loops or list interpretations? The grids will be large, so numpythony and speed are appreciated. What about non-sequential dimensions (e.g. axis=(0,2))?  Thanks!

Comment: Could you post runnable code, because that `magical_enumerate` is undefined?

Comment: Hi Divarak, this is shorthand of the kind I see used in SO, for "I don't know what to put here, but this is the kind of thing I am looking for." The code is just an example to help clarify the text.

Comment: I may have got it completely wrong, but can't you just reshape `F` and then perform `np.cross` like `np.sum(np.cross(F.reshape(-1,F.shape[-1]),vec),1)` and then use these values to set into `F`?

Comment: Divarak I've made a mistake, it should be `.sum(axis=0)`. Let me reconsider your suggestion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.ndindex` might do the trick.  It generates an iterator over a set of dimensions.

```
In [231]: F=np.zeros((2,3,3,3))

In [232]: for tup in np.ndindex(F.shape[:3]):
    # vec = data[tup] etc
    F[tup]=tup
   .....:     

In [233]: F
Out[233]: 
array([[[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  2.]],

         ...
         [ 1.,  2.,  1.],
         [ 1.,  2.,  2.]]]])
```

I'd suggest looking at the code for both `ndenumerate` and `ndindex`.  `ndindex` is using the more recent `nditer` in a `multi_index` mode.  `ndenumerate` uses `flat` to iterate over all values.

I've suggested in other SO how you could construct your own `multi_index` iterator modeled on `ndindex`.  A search on `nditer` might produce those.

This is not going to give a speed advantage over multiple loops, because you still are dealing with the same number of inner most calculations.

As for non-sequential dimensions, this same `ndindex` will work, but you have to manipulate `tup` before using it as an index:

```
In [243]: for tup in np.ndindex((F.shape[0],F.shape[2])):
    tup1=(tup[0],slice(None),tup[1])
    F[tup]=[tup[0],np.nan,tup[1]]
   .....:
```

`np.apply_along_axis` and `np.apply_over_axes` are other examples of generating indices over 1 or more of the axes, while slicing others.