# Most efficient way of iterating over a numpy array by axis?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

I have a numpy array with 3 dimensions. 
I want to iterate over 2 dims and pull everything out in the 3rd dim. 
I.E:

```
arr = numpy.random.rand(3,5,5)

for i in range(arr.shape[1]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[2]):
        print arr[:, i, j]
```

Is this the most efficient way to loop? I know numpy provides the more efficient `nditer` function for looping, but it doesn't seem like it is able to do stuff like this

The actual arrays I'll be using will have a size of about 30x256x256

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html#numpy-transpose) for this:

```
>>> x, y, z = arr.shape
>>> np.transpose(arr, (1, 2, 0)).reshape(y*z, x)
array([[  8.89189379e-01,   5.95637587e-01,   7.84594074e-01],
       [  4.46214496e-01,   6.95533725e-03,   5.99493854e-02],
       [  4.37458356e-01,   4.17801277e-01,   8.70384164e-01],
       [  1.22083367e-01,   3.15002894e-01,   9.61295653e-01],
       [  2.15219210e-01,   5.99682222e-01,   8.59042071e-01],
       [  7.39714387e-01,   6.06449305e-01,   1.53375491e-01],
       [  4.34580313e-01,   8.23793966e-01,   2.58262432e-01],
       [  6.53256475e-01,   9.10842288e-01,   6.62668876e-01],
       [  2.60638435e-01,   2.44083731e-01,   9.44411275e-01],
       [  3.46072029e-01,   3.36690811e-01,   5.56281161e-04],
       [  5.54365956e-01,   7.84576199e-01,   2.92020128e-01],
       [  6.98475648e-01,   7.59483427e-01,   8.09173748e-01],
       [  7.28369542e-01,   2.07783197e-01,   3.36918305e-01],
       [  3.64955373e-01,   2.09863710e-01,   4.68231831e-02],
       [  9.10347730e-01,   2.59136721e-01,   7.71923984e-01],
       [  6.86310347e-01,   5.99903493e-01,   1.93947009e-01],
       [  1.28353564e-01,   4.04525015e-01,   8.46140174e-01],
       [  4.54025659e-01,   8.81360670e-01,   4.43411994e-01],
       [  6.57856096e-01,   3.55154332e-02,   6.74960684e-01],
       [  8.58154335e-01,   2.44856092e-01,   7.33027949e-01],
       [  2.09503288e-01,   1.20565562e-01,   5.44488104e-01],
       [  4.67728847e-02,   6.54273408e-02,   4.70930711e-02],
       [  3.70647262e-02,   5.72090215e-01,   4.38541549e-01],
       [  7.30252318e-01,   4.96902990e-02,   5.80768124e-01],
       [  4.92665142e-01,   9.16531057e-01,   8.29183892e-01]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Adapting my answer from recent question, you can use `ndindex`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29467367/901925

```
for tup in np.ndindex((arr.shape[1:])):
    tup1=(slice(None),tup[0],tup[1])
    print arr[tup1]
```

This uses `nditer` to generate a `multi_index`, which can be combined with a `slice` to produce the desired index.

The `nditer` tutorial page also shows how a mix of `order` and `external_loop` properties can make an `nditer` return a sub_vector, but that is tricky.

`nditer` isn't more 'efficient' or faster.  You still end up indexing each element, or in your case a slice on the 1st dimension.  `nditer` is most useful as a step toward coding the problem `cython`.  In pure Python it is just as slow, even slower, than for loops.

`nditer` is also great when you need to step through several arrays in unison, e.g. `c[i] = a[i]+b[i]`.

If you must iterate over the last 2 dimensions, what you  are doing is probably as fast as any other method. Other methods just hide details.

You might explore swapping axes, or reshaping, e.g. `arr.reshape(3,-1)`.

```
for x in arr.reshape(3,-1).T:
    print(x)
```

This is my winner in speed.

Comment: hi @hpaulj, could you have a look at this Q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38207528/what-are-the-efficient-ways-to-loop-over-vectors-along-a-specified-axis-in-numpy  I had a feasible way from this A but I doubt it's the optimal.

Comment: For the `ndindex`, is it possible to make it say give me the indexes which would give me all the 2nd layers of all the columns of all the rows? For example a shape of `(3, 3, 3)`, I want to just iterate over `(0,0,1), (0,1,1), (0,2,1) ...`.

Comment: I wouldn't use `ndindex` for that, just do a 1d iteration: `for i in range(3): idx=(0, i, 1)`