# What are the efficient ways to loop over vectors along a specified axis in numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm processing data by looping over vectors along an axis (could be any axis) of numpy ndarray (could be of any dimensions).

I didn't work on array directly because the data are not perfect. It requires quality control on each vector. If not good, the vector will be filled by zeros (or nan) and not have a real processing.

I found [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493183/most-efficient-way-of-iterating-over-a-numpy-array-by-axis) similar but my problem is much more difficult because

1. `ndim` is arbitrary.

For a 3D array, I can take vectors along `axis 1` like this

```
 x = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
 for i in range(x.shape[0]):
     for k in range(x.shape[2]):
         process(x[i,:,k])
```

but if `ndim` and the taken `axis` are not fixed, how to take vectors?

2. The axis for taking vectors is arbitrary.

One possible way I'm considering is

```
 y = x.swapaxes(ax,-1)
 # loop over vectors along last axis
 for i in np.ndindex(y.shape[:-1]):
     process(y[i+(slice(None),)])
 # then swap back
 z = y.swapaxes(ax,-1)
```

But I'm doubting the efficiency of this method.

Comment: The most efficient way would be to **not** iterate/loop, that is modifying (if not applicable yet)  `process` to process all slices in one go. So, are you working with a specific `process` func? If not, look into `np.vectorize` I think.

Comment: I didn't work on array directly because the data array are not perfect. It requires quality control on each vector. If not good, the vector will be filled by zeros (or nan).

Comment: depending on the function `process` and the amount of looping, it might be worth it to use [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/)'s `jit` decorator

Comment: Are you able to elaborate a little more on why you want to process the data in linear vectors rather than as a whole array

Comment: You don't need the `swapaxes` in that last example - see my edits.

Comment: @VinceWest  For each vector, I need to check the validity of the time series by replacing irregular values (e.g., inf, nan) and glitches with zeros, and counting the non-zeros (abs values smaller than 1e-13 deemed as zeros). Vectors with non-zeros values below a threshold will be discarded and `zeros` or `nans` will be filled in the vector in the resulting array. For good vectors, some basic signal processings are applied, such as detrend, bandpass filtering. Other operations could be `rfft`, rolling-window calculations of `range`, `std`, `mean`, `median` ...

Comment: I like hpaulj's answer. If speed is absolutely critical you should consider constructing a number numba compiled functions to handle the variety of shapes you will be doing and then parse the input to determine which numba function to pass it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to test efficiency is to do time tests on realistic examples.  But `%timeit` (ipython) tests on toy examples are a start.

Based on experience from answering similar 'if you must iterate' questions, there isn't much difference in times.  `np.frompyfunc` has a modest speed edge - but its `pyfunc` takes scalars, not arrays or slices.  (`np.vectorize` is a nicer API to this function, and a bit slower).

But here you want to pass a 1d slice of an array to your function, while iterating over all the other dimensions.  I don't think there's much difference in the alternative iteration methods.

Actions like `swapaxis`, `transpose` and `ravel` are fast, often just creating a new view with different shape and strides.

`np.ndindex` uses `np.nditer` (with the multindex flat) to iterate over a range of dimensions.  `nditer` is fast when used in C code, but isn't anything special when used in Python code.

`np.apply_along_axis` creates a `(i,j,:,k)` indexing tuple, and steps the variables.  It's a nice general approach, but isn't doing anything special to speed things up.  `itertools.product` is another way of generating the indices.

But usually it isn't the iteration mechanism that slows things down, it's the repeated call to your function.  You can test the iteration mechanism by using a trivial function, e.g.

```
def foo(x):
   return x
```

===================

You don't need to `swapaxes` to use `ndindex`; you can use it to iterate on any combination of axes.

For example, make a 3d array, and sum along the middle dimension:

```
In [495]: x=np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4)

In [496]: N=np.ndindex(2,4)

In [497]: [x[i,:,k].sum() for i,k in N]
Out[497]: [12, 15, 18, 21, 48, 51, 54, 57]

In [498]: x.sum(1)
Out[498]: 
array([[12, 15, 18, 21],
       [48, 51, 54, 57]])
```

I don't think it makes a difference in speed; the code's just simpler.

===================

Another possible tool is `np.ma`, masked arrays.  With those you mark individual elements as masked (because they are `nan` or `0`).  It has code that evaluates things like `sum`, `mean`, `product` in such a way that the masked values don't harm the solution.

The 3d array again:

```
In [517]: x=np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4)
```

add in some bad values:

```
In [518]: x[1,1,2]=99    
In [519]: x[0,0,:]=99
```

those values mess up the normal `sum`:

```
In [520]: x.sum(axis=1)
Out[520]: 
array([[111, 113, 115, 117],
       [ 48,  51, 135,  57]])
```

but if we mask them, they are 'filtered out' of the solution (in this case, they are set temporarily to 0)

```
In [521]: xm=np.ma.masked_greater(x,50)

In [522]: xm
Out[522]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[[-- -- -- --]
  [4 5 6 7]
  [8 9 10 11]]

 [[12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 -- 19]
  [20 21 22 23]]],
             mask =
 [[[ True  True  True  True]
 ...
  [False False False False]]],
       fill_value = 999999)

In [523]: xm.sum(1)
Out[523]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[12 14 16 18]
 [48 51 36 57]],
 ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [`numpy.nditer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html#numpy.nditer)?

See also [Iterating over arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#arrays-nditer).

EDIT: maybe another solution would just be to either use:

- `flatten`
- `ravel`
- the `flat` 1D iterator

You can thus iterate 1D-like whatever the array's initial dim, and then `reshape` the array to its original shape.

Comment: I got similar idea using `np.ndindex` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493183/most-efficient-way-of-iterating-over-a-numpy-array-by-axis  but it also mentioned that `nditer` is even slower than for loop.

Comment: In fact, the builtin functions of numpy, as `mean, sum, fft, ...`, can always deal with ndarray regardless what `ndim` and `axis`. But I didn't get how they make it, even though I took a look at the source codes.

Comment: I think they actually wrap pre-compiled C  code (in which loops do occur), see [What is numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/whatisnumpy.html).
Have you considered the possibility to check your data using some of numpy's vectorized functions (see for example http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html) and numpy [indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) which is really powerful?
If you definitely need to loop, maybe you should consider [Cython](http://cython.org/) and use it to write looping C code natively callable from Python